# The “Unable to verify link” got mixed content warning and borked favicon

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, ssl

Stack Exchange use their own advertisement redirection mechanism for various advertisements. When something there goes wrong, they show a friendly error page.

[Link to reproduce](https://clc.stackoverflow.com/click?an=AXAAj_8KTwa8PxOK1EgtngRMSQICEIPf4hSWowxG6_qwSD1INmsB8U7cUMhRAAQAjLAAAIA_AQEAAhsC9KoHi-AI5eIPCgQABMCSGAk6rNk5PxsC_qcHnNwIkdsPAgQAweSEGe05eylVPwBDcPnXPHoG3RNB&cr=257425&ct=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fjobs).

As you can see, the page is not secure due to a borked favicon URL:

> [image]

Can this please be fixed?

Also, the links to MSE are not https://, while there is redirection think it's better to have correct links.

Comment: Thanks, you're entirely right - thanks for the report.

Comment: @Marc no problem. Fix is planned then?

Comment: I've bumped the people who own that area - I can't advise further than that, and : timezones

Comment: @Marc oh, forgot different people work on different things, i.e. one dev can't fix anything. Thanks again!

Comment: We'll take a look at the favicon, but, just curious, did you originally reach that page in error? In other words, did a link we generated send you there, or did you edit the click link yourself to see what happens?

Comment: @Bret I was afraid you'll ask that... Well, I admit editing it to try and see what happens. :)

Comment: It's perfectly fine. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't more broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up! This was something that slipped through the cracks when we converted our job ad serving application to HTTPS only. Fix is going up now.

Comment: Wait, aren't you on the Careers/Jobs team? Thanks anyway, of course! :) (oh wait, only Jobs ads got such redirection?)

Comment: I'm _officially_ on our Ad Server team, but I have my toes in quite a few things :)

Comment: Fix confirmed, thanks! What about the links to MSE? Any chance to change them to https as well?

Comment: _...derp_

Yes, I'll get those fixed right up. Thanks... 